# Removing unwanted characters after extension

Tags: .htaccess

I have pages that are called via a query strung from a cgi.

```
xyz.cgi?page=abc.html
```

The problem that I have is that I get bot requests for pages that do exist, but the request has characters after the `.html` and the result is a 404.

Is there a way in `.htaccess` to strip off everything after the `.html` extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule to remove  chars after the html extension :

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+\.html).+$ /$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect

```
/foo.htmlchars
```

to

```
/foo.html
```

Or

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.+\.html).+$ /$1
```

EDIT :

To redirect **/xyz.cgi?page=foo.htmlchars** to **/xyz.cgi?page=foo.html** you may using the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /xyz\.cgi\?page=(.+\.html).+\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /xyz.cgi?page=%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does work, but unfortunately not with query string.

Comment: You people are beautiful!  I can't tell you how many times over the years I have had my problems solved and how to questions answered.  All that I needed to do was add the path to the cgi and it worked like a charm.