# removing unwanted characters after image extension in a string

Tags: python

I got a few img urls which I need to download. I see some urls have unwanted characters after the image extension, which I need to remove/delete before the download.

For example the following url contains `?6ce6a3=` after the jpeg extension, which needs to be removed; the image extensions could be `png`, `jpg`, `jpeg` or `gif`. I need your input how to do it. Do I need to use a regex or a function already available in python. I know various `strip()` methods are available, but I am not sure which one works best. A little guidance will be helpful. I have found a similar question here: [Removing unwanted characters after extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192550/removing-unwanted-characters-after-extension) but you got to know your extension beforehand, however.

```
url = 'http://4.kicksonfire.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/12.jpeg?6ce6a3='
print os.path.basename(url) # result 12.jpeg?6ce6a3=
print os.path.splitext(url)[1] # .jpeg?6ce6a3=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.basename()` in combination with `str.partition()`:

```
print os.path.basename(url).partition("?")[0]
```