# How to strip everything after first '/' In .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the below in my .htaccess file to redirect all traffic from an old domain to a new domain.

All traffic should go to the home page.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^http://www.olddomain.co.uk/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.olddomain.co.uk/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^olddomain.co.uk/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

This works fine for the homepage but for the other pages this doesn't work as the urls look something like:

http://www.olddomain.org.uk/index.php?p=214&pp=3&page=Volunteer

These are redirecting to an error page as opposed to a homepage.

I want to strip everything out that comes after the first / after the domain name but I do not know how to do this.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: maybe this link can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192550/removing-unwanted-characters-after-extension

Comment: @AndersKink Thanks for that link.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the code but that did not work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(www.)?olddomain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/? [R=301,NC,L]
```